# How do I use Heroku to host a personal website?

Tags: heroku, frontend

I want to use Heroku to host a website that has HTML, CSS and JS files, along with some jpegs and gifs.

I know how to do this with a Rails application, using;

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

It seems that the cedar stack create a repo that is fit for Rails, Java ect apps because the error message is

```
Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

And when I try to launch the app it just say; Heroku | Welcome to your new app!

Here is a link: http://afternoon-brook-2543.herokuapp.com/

So I want to know how to put some JS, HTML, CSS and images files to host. Perhaps another command may create a simple website stack?

Comment: I have a Heroku app that is just static HTML, CSS, and JS files, but I created a thin Sinatra app around it to serve everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you saved your root file as index.php then Heroku will detect it as a PHP application - it doesn't need to actually contain PHP code, just been named that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a personal website into Heroku, create an index.php file connected to your website. Launch the app as it was a PHP app. You will be able to launch the app with ease!

Hope this helped!